How to solve special ATM case for Hagan approximation?
In Hagan et al's original SABR paper (https://www.next-finance.net/IMG/pdf/pdf_SABR.pdf), how do we reduce (2.17a) to (2.18) for the special ATM case?  Could someone help walk me through the algebra?  I can't seem to work out the math.  It looks like if z/x(z) is equal to 1, then it's rather easy to see, but I can't understand why z/x(z) equals 1.  It's been a while since I did actual math, so hopefully this question isn't too silly... Thanks for your help.

It seems like $z=0$ for $f=K$, as you get $log(1)=0$ and $x(0)=log(\frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho}) = log(1) = 0$. Which makes the term $z/x(z)$ undefined. Even when trying  to just "plug everything in" I get the last part of equation 2.18, but I get $v$ as the leading factor and not $\frac{\alpha}{f^{1-\beta}}$.
So it seems like you need to accept the convention $\frac{0}{0} = 1$ to derive the equation 2.18 from 2.17a.
